# Error:float argument required, not dict

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to write the output to a file.

```
import time
start_time = time.clock()
import os
completeName = os.path.abspath("New Volume (F:)/New Innings/eigenvalues .txt")
file = open("eigenvalues.txt", "w")
import sympy as sp
from sympy.matrices import *
k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,x,z = sp.symbols('k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,x,z')
I=Matrix([[-k5*(k1+k3),k2,k3*x+k4],[k2,-k2,0],[-k3*z,0,-k3*x-k4]])
Z=I.eigenvals()
print Z
file.write("%float\n" % Z)
file.close()
print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

But I am getting an error corresponding to

```
file.write("%float\n" % Z)
```

which says

```
TypeError: float argument required, not dict
```

Comment: You're doing string formatting with `%` but within your string you're saying "my variable will be a float" with `%f` when in fact Z is a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments already, you're formatting your string with `%` but you are passing a dictionary as an argument. `%float` is expecting a float but you have given it a dict `Z`.

To resolve this, you can use the [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method instead, so your `file.write` becomes

```
file.write("{}\n".format(Z))
```